# youtube embed behaviour in google cast receivever

Tags: youtube-api, google-cast

I have been working on the receiver in the google cast sdk. I have mutiple youtube videos and mp4 videos in cloud and i have an app that has these videos. I am able to able to cast the youtube videos but when i click on the mp4 link i cannot get back control to the receiver. 
Anybody any help?`

```js
var player;
function onYouTubePlayer(videoId) {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '720',
    width: '1280',
    videoId: videoId,
    playerVars: { autoplay:1, controls:1, showinfo: 0, rel: 0, showsearch: 0, iv_load_policy: 3, enablejsapi:1,listType:'playlist',
          list: playlist},
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
      'onError': catchError
    }
  });
}

  var done = false;
  var playlist;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      done = true;
    } else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
      event.target.destroy();
      location.reload();
    }else if(event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED){
      location.reload();
    }

  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {

    //if(typeof(SONG.getArtistId()) == undefined)
    //{
    //  console.log("undefineeeed"); 
    //} 
     player.addEventListener('onStateChange', function(e) {
        console.log('State is:', e.data);
    });
    event.target.playVideo();   
  }
  function catchError(event)
  {
    if(event.data == 100) console.log("This Video does not exist!!");
  }

  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }



/**
 * Called when we receive a LOAD message. Calls load().
 *
 * @see sampleplayer#load
 * @param {cast.receiver.MediaManager.Event} event The load event.
 * @private
 */ 
sampleplayer.CastPlayer.prototype.onLoad_ = function(event) {
  this.log_('onLoad_');
  this.log_(event.data);
          // handler for the CastMessageBus message event
  this.messageBus.onMessage = function(event) {
          this.log_('Message [' + event.senderId + ']: ' + event.data);
          // display the message from the sender
          // inform all senders on the CastMessageBus of the incoming message event
          // sender message listener will be invoked
          this.messageBus.send(event.senderId, event.data);
  }

  var videoId = event.data.media.contentId.split("?v=")[1];
  if(event.data.media.contentId.includes("youtube.com")){
  if (typeof(YT) == 'undefined' || typeof(YT.Player) == 'undefined') {
   
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function() {
      onYouTubePlayer(videoId);
    };

  } else {

    onYouTubePlayer(videoId);

  }
}else{

}
  this.cancelDeferredPlay_('new media is loaded');
  this.load(new cast.receiver.MediaManager.LoadInfo(
      /** @type {!cast.receiver.MediaManager.LoadRequestData} */ (event.data),
      event.senderId));
};
```

`